# How to update images with imageview from code

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an app that displays images continuosly (4 or 5 times per second) so i need to update an image held inside a ImageView object, it works if i trigger the functions from a button press, every time i press the button the next image gets displayed:

```
int i = 0;
public void buttonPressed(View view) {
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    String path = String.format("/storage/emulated/0/Download/%d.bmp", i);
    File imgFile = new File(path);
    bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
    i++;
    }
```

But if i try to call the same functions more than once in the same parent function or i try to run them in a loop the first images are not loaded at all and only the last is finally displayed after loopFunc() completed:

```
public void loopFunc() {
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
 for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    String path = String.format("/storage/emulated/0/Download/%d.bmp", i);
    File imgFile = new File(path);
    bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
    //wait some time or do other things...
    }
}
```

In few words i need to be able to execute `image.setImageBitmap(bMap);` from code and not from buttons anyone knows how? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the time you used to compute other things. Is there some kind of delay function code you wrote in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Just make a function and call it onCreate method with some Thread or Handler.

```
public void imgViwer()
    {
        Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
                    String path = String.format("/storage/emulated/0/Download/%d.bmp", i);
                    File imgFile = new File(path);
                    bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
}
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

After every 200ms your loop works.

Answer (score 0):

**Root cause**

Because the loop is run too quickly in a short time, that why you see the first image is not displayed at all, and only the last is finally displayed after `loopFunc()` completed.

**Solution**

To display a sequence of images continuously per second, then you should use [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler).

```
public void loopFunc() {
    Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    int totalImage = 3;
    for (int i = 1; i < totalImage; i++) {
        int imageIndex = i;
        mainHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String path = String.format("/storage/emulated/0/Download/%d.bmp", imageIndex);
                File imgFile = new File(path);
                bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
            }
        }, 1000 / totalImage * imageIndex);
    }
}
```